# Logitech Performance MX mouse and K800 keyboard

Tags: windows-10

I have a pc with windows 10. Unplugged everything and opened it to hook up a dvd with a SATA cable. Closed it back up and plugged it in. Computer comes on but my wireless mouse and keyboard don’t work. I re-paired the receiver at a friends house and both devices worked fine. They still won’t work on mine. I tested all USB ports with a portable fan and they are all working. Any suggestions as to the disconnect would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going back to a state where everything worked (removing the DVD drive) and see if that fixes the keyboard and mouse problem. Also check cables going to USB port, both at motherboard and where it connects to case, maybe a cable came loose while you were installing DVD.